# The image of a relatively weakly compact is also rel. weakly compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $T: X \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear operator, where $X$, $Y$ are Banach spaces.

**Claim:** If $A$ is relatively weakly compact, then $T(A)$ is too.

Actually, I don't know whether this statement is true or false, but it what I need to prove my main goal:

> Let $S \circ T: X \rightarrow Z \rightarrow Y$, where $Z$ is
>   reflexive. Then $S \circ T$ is a weakly compact operator.

As it turns out that $T(B_X)$ is rel. $w$-compact, I only need the claim to end this.

So, is the claim true? If so, how to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

1. Choose any net $(x_i)$ in $A$.
2. By relative weak compactness, there is a subnet $(x'_j)$ of $(x_i)$ weakly convergent to some $x'$.
3. Since $T$ is bounded, it is also weak-weak continuous and $(T(x'_j))$ converges weakly to $T(x')$.
4. Since $(x_i)$ was arbitrary (and hence so was $(T(x_i))$) and $(T(x'_j))$ is a weakly convergent subnet of $(T(x_i))$, $T(A)$ is weakly compact.

(If you don't like nets, you can apply Eberlein–Šmulian and use sequences instead, but it's not necessary.)

More generally, the continuous image of a relatively compact set is relatively compact by essentially the same argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But if you don't mind I need some explanation about 2. Why rel. weak compactness is equivalent to that condition? I feel like it is the same than in rel. compactness (in norm), but I don't know the reason in neither case.

Comment: @Minkowski: You are right, this is not obvious (although the direction used in 2. is fairly obvious). I suspect this is requires the $T_3$ separation axiom (which is not a problem, because weak topology is completely regular by Hahn-Banach). I'll try to work this out.

Comment: I think the following argument should work. Take any net $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ in $\overline A\subseteq X$. We need to show that it has a limit point. Suppose towards contradiction that it has no limit point. Then by regularity, for each $x\in X$ you can find disjoint open sets $U_x,V_x$ such that $x\in U_x$ and almost all $a_i\in V_x$.

Comment: It follows that for each finite set $S=\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$ you can find a net $(a_{S,i,j})_{i\in I,j\in J_S}$ of elements of $A$ such that almost all $a_{i,j}$ are in $V_{x_1}\cap\ldots\cap V_{x_n}$ (just take $i$ large enough so that $a_i\in V_{x_1}\cap\ldots\cap V_{x_n}$ and ensure that $(a_{S,i,j})_j$ "uniformly converge" to $a_i$). Then the net $(a_{S,i,j})_{i\in I, S\subseteq X\textrm{ finite}, j\in J_S}$ with the lexicographic order has no convergent subnet.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of relative compactness being a topological invariant under continuous mappings between topological spaces.